# Solving a number theory problem

Tags: number-theory

LCM is an abbreviation used for Least Common Multiple in Mathematics. We say LCM (a, b, c) = L if and only if L is the least integer which is divisible by a, b and c.
If I'm given a, b and L I have to find c such that LCM (a, b, c) = L.

If there are several solutions, I have to choose the one where c is as small as possible.
How can i do this.Can anyone give any hints? It is worthy of mentioning that $1 ≤ a, b ≤ 10^6, 1 ≤ L ≤ 10^{12}$.

Answer (score 1):

$lcm(a,b,c)=lcm(lcm(a,b),c)$. Let $d=lcm(a,b)$

So you need to solve the problem of finding smallest $c$ so that $lcm(d,c)=L$. to find this number take $\frac{L}{d}$ and let $lcm(\frac{L}{d},d)=l$. The value for $c$ that you want is $\frac{L}{d}\cdot l$

Answer (score 0):

If $a=p_1^{a1}p_2^{a2}p_3^{a3}...$ and $b=q_1^{b1}q_2^{b2}q_3^{b3}...$ where the $p$ and $q$ are primes and the exponents are integers, then the $c$ which can fit in are those with each prime factor raised to a power no greater than it was in either $a$ or $b$. avid19's answer, for example, takes each exponent to be zero, certainly satisfying that upper bound.

Comment: this doesn't include $L$ at all.

Comment: As I understood if, he was asking for hints rather than an explicit answer, so I was describing the thought process behind it.